# Tests to Assess Collaboration Skills

Tags: test, collaboration

We are trying to map people collaboration skills and aptitudes, in a business context. In particular we are interested in the following personality traits:

- Intrinsic Motivation
- Attitude to risk
- Empathy (We mean: (1) I try to be on time whenever possible, independent of who the other person is; (2) I consider my collaborators also my friends)
- Trust (We mean: Do I trust other people in the group?)
- Tendency to ethical behavior

Do you have any suggestions of pre-existing tests which can help in mapping such constructs? Constructs can be renamed, I'm not sure we are using the most appropriate language.

Would you include other traits to the aim of assessing collaboration skills?

Comment: "try to be on time...consider my collaborators also my friends" -> This is not the definition of empathy. You can be empathetic without being friends with someone, and being friends with or being on time for someone does not mean you are displaying empathy.